# Regular expression that match a text if it contains a string ONLY once

Tags: regex, string

I would like to write a regular expression that matches a text if it contains a string ONLY once. The text must contain `<scr>` only once. Here are some examples:

`hello-<scr>Keephello-endofstring`   //ok; `<scr>` occurs once

`test-<scr>bla<scr>bla-end`   //NOT ok; `<scr>` occurs 2 times

`hello-Keephello-end`   //NOT ok; `<scr>` doesn't occur

I tried with the following regex:

```
((?:(?<!<scr>).)*<scr>(?:(?!<scr>).)*)
```

The first negative lookbehind ensures that `<scr>` doesn't occur.
Than `<scr>` must follow.
After this a negative lookahead ensures that no more `<scr>` follow.

It does not work.
I would like to know how this can be done with regex? (with explanation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if text contains some substring only once, you need to check match all characters that do not constitute `<scr>`, then match `<scr>`, and use a negative look-ahead to check if there is no `<scr>` further, and consume all characters. Also, line/string boundaries `^`/`$` are  a must:

```
^(?:(?!<scr>).)*<scr>(?!.*<scr>).*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ0gU0/3)

**EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of line (as `m` multiline option is ON)
- `(?:(?!<scr>).)*` - A non-capturing group to match each character (not a newline - for that, you need to also add `s` singleline option) that is not preceded with `<scr>`
- `<scr>` - Our literal `<scr>`
- `(?!.*<scr>)` - The negative lookbehind checking that we do not have `<scr>` any more
- `.*$` - Subpattern matching the rest of the characters to the end of the line.

Comment: Based upon the regex from @stribizhev, this is the code for matching n occurrences of  `<scr>`:  ^((?:(?!<scr>).)*(?:<scr>(?:(?!<scr>).)*){2,2})$. The first part   `(?:(?!<scr>).)*`  doesn't allow `<scr>`. The second part  `(?:<scr>(?:(?!<scr>).)*){2,2}`  means: `<scr>` followed by a text, that doesn't contains `<scr>`. The second part is repeated 2 times. This regex matches a text, that contains  `<scr>`  exactly two times.

Comment: Instead of `{2,2}` you may just use `{2}`. Also, there is no need adding round brackets round the whole expression as you always can access the whole match via Group 0. This just a hint how to make this regex "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right, it's only missing `^` and `$` anchors to make sure that your regex matches the whole string. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/rZ0gU0/1) for an example.