# Regex: match only if word occurs once

Tags: regex

I would like this to ONLY return a match if there is no more than one 'Yes'.

**EXAMPLE:**

**This would be a match:**
Event 1 (Yes)
Event 2 (No)
Event 3 (No)

**This would NOT be a match:**
Event 1 (Yes)
Event 2 (No)
Event 3 (Yes)

I've tried so many different combinations based on other answers I've found.

Comment: ["To check if text contains some substring only once, you need to check match all characters that do not constitute <scr>, then match <scr>, and use a negative look-ahead to check if there is no <scr> further, and consume all characters. Also, line/string boundaries ^/$ are a must"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144801/regular-expression-that-match-a-text-if-it-contains-a-string-only-once) Here's a link to a solution

Comment: @JLL Please provide what you have tried(some code snippet) and where it is failing(some error or unexpected output).

Comment: There are cleaner ways to do that. Find all occurrences of the word `Yes` (if you do not need a whole word match, you may even use non-regex methods that your language provides) and then check the count. If the count is 1, the string is valid.

Comment: @PremusVitka Thank you. I edited your link to:

^(?:(?!Yes).)*Yes(?!.*Yes).*$

And it gave no match for either of my examples above. Perhaps I can't do this with Regex?

Comment: Is it because I have line breaks in my text? If I add /gm it finds one match for my first example (correct) and two matches for the second (incorrect).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can match one Yes with:

```
^([^Y]|Y[^e]|Ye[^s])*Yes([^Y]|Y[^e]|Ye[^s])*$
```

assuming you are using Perl or PCRE regex.